# Is there an advantage to setting a device to dhcp and assigning an ip via dhcp vs setting a static ip?

Tags: ip, dhcp

I've always hard coded my devices to have their own ips. But lately I've read that allowing dhcp to do that for me might be beneficial. I'm not sure I agree with it but I thought I'd see what everyone else does.

This is in a /22 network with nearly 300 devices.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DHCP has the benefit of central management and potential scripting.

If you intended to split your network into /24 subnets it'd be very doable with DHCP. Additionally, you can very easily change options such as DNS servers, gateways, domains, NTP, ...

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule of thumb, it is good to have critical equipment such as routers, switches and servers hard coded with an IP. End User devices, on the other hand should be handled via DHCP. There are many thing you can do with DHCP especially if you want to get into FQDN and setting different flags.

I should also mention that the routers and switches would be on a management network and the servers would be on another network. This would even more solidify the possibility of not having any conflicts with your end users and your critical equipment.

Flat topologies are usually bad thing to do. especially with that many on a /22.
A /23 would give you enough for 300 users. Then you could make a /24 or even smaller for your network equipment/servers.

Answer (score 0):

Say for example you have an ip conflict with one of your servers and all your machines are statically assigned IPs ... that would be a nightmare to troubleshoot (especially with 300 machines as you stated). With DHCP there is a benefit of (provided the scopes are setup correctly) that that problem would almost never happen